# Program will only crash when it's not connected to a real terminal - how to debug?

Tags: c, terminal, gdb

I have a program that crashes with a

```
segfault at 1 ip 0000000000000001 sp 0000000008077d60 error 14
```

whenever it's not connected to a real terminal, e.g. `./program > log.txt &` will crash. Running it normally doesn't lead to this strange behavior.
I wanted to see if gdb can help me finding the cause for this, but of course just running it in gdb won't trigger the bug.

What does however is

```
echo r | gdb ./program
```

But then gdb will immediately exit when the program crashes:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000001 in ?? ()
(gdb) quit
A debugging session is active.

    Inferior 1 [process 15434] will be killed.

Quit anyway? (y or n) [answered Y; input not from terminal]
```

I've tried `echo -e "r\nbt" | gdb` already, but it won't behave any different.

Comment: Inside gdb you should be able to redirect your program's stdout using redirection on the run command: `(gdb) run > outfile`  Does that work to repro the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do:

```
gdb ./program
```

and once you're in there, do:

```
run < log.txt
```

to direct in your input, or:

```
run > log.txt
```

to redirect the output, as desired.